# Practice PSAT Question About Rational Functions

Tags: rational-functions, constants, multinomial-coefficients

This is taken directly from a PSAT Practice Test:

> $f(x)=\dfrac{2x-4}{2x^2+2x-4}$
>   A rational function is defined above. Which of the following is an equivalent form that displays values not included in the domain as constants or coefficients?
>
> A) $f(x)=\dfrac{x-2}{x^2+x-2}$
>
> B) $f(x)=\dfrac{2(x-2)}{2(x+2)(x-1)}$
>
> C) $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x+1}$
>
> D)$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2x^2}$

My understanding is that this question is asking for the form that includes $-2$, and $1$ as either a coefficient or constant, and is equal to the original equation. Both A and B seem to satisfy this, both of them have $-2$ as a constant, and 1 as a coefficient.

The answer key in the back says it is B, but I and a few of my teachers thought it was A, since A was a simpler version of B. What are we doing wrong here?

Comment: In option A, I see both the constant $-2$ and the coefficient $1$. In option B, I do not see the coefficient $1$.

Comment: @barakmanos Ah, my bad. I meant to say "...includes -2 and 1 as either ..." up above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factoring the denominator, as in (b), displays the values not included in the domain plainly.  It's clear by inspection that $-2, 1$ aren't in the domain when looking at choice (b), whereas it's not in (a).

Comment: But isn't the question asking if -2 and 1 are constants and/or coefficients? Sure b may show them more clearly, but doesn't A also show them?

Comment: I can "see" that $x+2 = 0$ when $x=-2$.  I can "see" that $x-1=0$ when $x=1$. The purpose of factoring is so that you can "see" the roots.  (Just trying to get into the head of the person writing the question, that's all.)  The factored version shows the values not included in the domain as constants (via the terms $(x-b)$ where $b$ is a root of the polynomial).

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. I understand that B is more clear than A, but I don't think that that would invalidate it.

Comment: Choices (a) and (b) are the same function as in the question, but (b) "displays" $-2, 1$, while (a) doesn't. It's not the best question in the world, but that's all I've got for you! :)

Comment: To clarify:  *Your* question *here* is fine!  The PSAT question is a tad odd.

Comment: Ah, okay. I see that "display" might be the keyword here. A _does_ have some coefficients of $1$,but since it is $1$,  they don't bother _displaying_ it and therefore doesn't count. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be (b). The domain does not include -2 and 1.  Answer (a) has "-2" as a constant (for x-2 and x^2+x-2) and "1" as a coefficient (for x^2(="1"*x^2) and x terms). No values other than "-2" and "1" as constants or coefficients are in (a). 
Though (b) has "-2" as a constant for x-2 and "1" as a coefficient for x+2 (="1"*x+2), x-2, and x-1, (b) also has "+2" as a constant for x+"2" and as a coefficient for 2(x+2).

Comment: Welcome to math stackexchange. You should write your posts with [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)